# Best practice to design django forms for CRUD operations

Tags: python, django, crud

I am building a django web application for admin which mainly involves CRUD (create,read, update and delete) operations. 
I need suggestions/best practices to design the forms. I am new to django and python and need experts suggestions.
Currently I have created different methods in the views like

```
def create(request):
    --logic to add
     return HttpResponseRedirect('/createproduct')

def delete(request,obj_id):                
    result=products.objects.get(product_type=object_id).delete()                              
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/listobjects/')

def getObjects(request):
    products= products.objects.order_by('product_type')
    return render(request,'getProducts.html',
                {'results': products})
```

and my urls.py is like below

```
url(r'^createproduct/$',create),
url(r'^listobjects/',getObjects),
url(r'^deleteproduct/(?P<object_id>\d+)/$',delete)
```

Comment: I am new to Django as well, and one thing that I have started doing, and would suggest you to do as well as a starting place, is take a look at the admin code that come with Django at `django/contrib/admin/*`. Here you can see some good examples of views, templates, etc., that you can either use directly, imitate, or take inspiration from.

Comment: Take a look at Django's class-based views. There are generic views for listing objects, displaying a single object in detail, updating an object, creating a new object, and more. Also, if you are looking to create a REST API, then have a look at the Django Rest Framework package.

Class based views: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/

Django Rest Framework: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/#quickstart

Answer (score 3):

Your CRUD operations seems pretty straightforward, so in this case try using Django's [Class Based Generic Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/).

As the doc states, this is one of the purposes they were created for:

> Django’s generic views were developed take certain common idioms and
>   patterns found in view development and abstract them so that you can
>   quickly write common views of data without having to write too much
>   code.
>
> We can recognize certain common tasks, like displaying a list of
>   objects, and write code that displays a list of any object. Then the
>   model in question can be passed as an extra argument to the URLconf.

Django ships with generic views to do the following:

- Display list and detail pages for a single object.
- Present date-based objects in year/month/day archive pages, associated detail, and “latest” pages.
- **Allow users to create, update, and delete objects – with or without authorization.**

Then you can create its [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/) and have a well designed codebase.

Answer (score 1):

Class based views are the answer. With class based views:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import (CreateView, DeleteView, UpdateView)

class MyView(CreateView):
    model = MyModel
```

is enough to give you a working view. Replace CreateView with UpdateView and DeleteView. This gives you all the validation in your model and automatically saves the data. You can use a list view for listing your data. You override the methods in the views to change anything you need. With this way, you aren't giving non-admins access to the admin interface. Keep the admin interface for admins. You should not be building whole websites in it.

Also, instead of using functions as views use the TemplateView instead from `django.views.generic`. It makes your code a lot cleaner. You can separate post from get, and have instance methods tied to your view.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is really a crud interface to django models, you may as well use the `django.contrib.admin` app which is designed to do exactly that. Just give users permissions to admin only the objects they need.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/

Comment: Not sure why I am getting downvoted, since the OP gave no information on the requirements and I assume he is perfectly able to judge by himself if the admin fits his use case. Anyway, a useful addition to django generic CBVs if you are building cruds is extra views: https://django-extra-views.readthedocs.io/en/latest/